# How to switch Matlab plot tick labels to scientific form?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a semilogarithmic plot which works so far with `semilogx`. Now I would like to change the tick labels. Now it says 10^8 10^9 ... 10^13, but I would like to see 1e8, 1e9, ... 1e13 on the x-axis. How can I change that?

Cheers
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `XTickLabels` property using your own format:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabels',sprintfc('1e%i',0:numel(xt)-1))
```

where [sprintfc](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) is an undocumented function creating cell arrays filled with custom strings and `xt` is the `XTick` you have fetched from the current axis in order to know how many of them there are.

Example with dummy data:

```
clear
clc
close all

x = 0:100000;
y = log(x);

figure
semilogx(x,y)

xt = get(gca,'XTick');

set(gca,'XTickLabels',sprintfc('1e%i',0:numel(xt)-1))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just changed it to    
 
`xt = get(gca,'XTick');
set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintfc('1e%i',log10(xt(1)):log10(xt(numel(xt))))); `

to get the actual values, not values starting from zero.